# CSS property print-color-adjust for non-webkit browsers

Tags: html, firefox, css, cross-browser

I'm looking for a property which will have the same effect as `-webkit-print-color-adjust` does in Safari, but Firefox and Explorer.

Will you please suggest to me such a property, if it exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No such property exists at this time.  Many browser vendors consider all printing specifications to be at the discretion of the user.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the [CSS Working Group's](https://wiki.csswg.org/) Color Module 4 draft now includes [color-adjust](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color-4/#color-adjust). I'm hoping that it will find its way into browsers in the future, as I also have been looking for a cross-browser alternative to `-webkit-print-color-adjust`.

The proposal pretty much matches the behavior of [-webkit-print-color-adjust](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust). It has two values:

- `economy` (default) allows the printer to use its default ink-saving mode.
- `exact` hints that the printer should preserve the colors.