# How to adjust Internet Explorer settings using C#

Tags: c#, html, css, wpf, internet-explorer

I am creating a web application. So I have an html web page which contains table with data. Also there is an image under the table. The image is like substratum or bottom layer. Internet Explorer shows this html file correctly. However, when user need to print this html page, then it is necessary to customize Internet Explorer settings. So the user has to make:

*Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced tab -> Printing section -> print background images and colours*

I would like to run Internet Explorer with this given option.

Comment: I'll be surprised if you have the option to even do this. You might like to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660148/html-css-styling-for-print-background-color-and-image-would-not-show-in-ie-an

Comment: To add on the previous comment, you can specify CSS print options and usually work around no background colors/images (define borders, change text color, etc). Or you could add an instruction for viewers how to enable printing background colors -- Print preview > Page Setup > Print background colors and images

Comment: You won't be able to change those printing options in IE programatically - but you could try having the image as an <img /> tag (rather than a CSS background) and positioning/z-indexing it behind the other content so that it appears as if it were background?

Answer (score 1):

Use `<img>` tag if you want to images to show on print.

You can also use borders of 0 height divs with border size the same as your panel size for color backgrounds.